# How to capture "finish_reason" after each crawl

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to capture "finish_reason" in scrapy after each crawl and insert this info into a database. The crawl instance is created in a pipeline before first item is collected.

It seems like I have to use the "engine_stopped" signal but couldn't find an example on how or where should I put my code to do this?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

One of possible options is to override `scrapy.statscollectors.MemoryStatsCollector` ([docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html#scrapy.statscollectors.MemoryStatsCollector),[code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.6.0/scrapy/statscollectors.py#L54-L61)) and it's `close_spider` method:

`middleware.py`:

```
import pprint
from scrapy.statscollectors import MemoryStatsCollector, logger

class MemoryStatsCollectorSender(MemoryStatsCollector):
    #Override close_spider method
    def close_spider(self, spider, reason):
        #finish_reason in reason variable
        #add your data sending code here
        if self._dump:
            logger.info("Dumping Scrapy stats:\n" + pprint.pformat(self._stats),
                        extra={'spider': spider})
        self._persist_stats(self._stats, spider)
```

Add newly created stats collector class to `settings.py`:

`STATS_CLASS = 'project.middlewares.MemoryStatsCollectorSender'`
`#STATS_CLASS = 'scrapy.statscollectors.MemoryStatsCollector'`